# How to compress and uncompress JPEG using lossless method?

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, compression

How to compress and uncompress JPEG using lossless method?

Comment: Do you want to losslessly compress a raster image into a JPEG, or losslessly compress a JPEG into another format?  If the latter, you will have to decompress it first.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy codec. You'd be better off with PNG. Whilst there is lossless JPEG, I think you'll find next to no support for it.

Comment: Sounds awkward but there are some lossless operations you can perform on JPEG like cropping (if the new offset and size are offsets of 8) and rotating, maybe this is the question? See http://www.betterjpeg.com/crop.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's specified in the JPEG standard but few encoders support it.  Use a lossless image format like PNG.

Answer (score 3):

The [Intel IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) contains a codec that supports the lossless version of the JPEG standard.  Certain medical devices use this format and probably nobody else in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Using the normal JPEG you can set the quality to 100% (or 1.0), but I don't think you'll ever get completely lossless compression because this is lossy by definition.

There is [Lossless JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) but it's a completely different algorithm, but I can't find any evidence of how well it's supported.

If you have any choice in the matter use png instead.

Comment: there are both method, even lossless